# iOS9: UITextField is not allowing to Copy/Paste

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ios9

In older versions, copy, paste and other symbols were coming. But in iOS9, it is not. How to enable these options in iOS9?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code in your viewController.

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a category which was intended for only one particular view but through `#import`'s all over the place it caused every `UITextField` in the app to not perform any actions. This seemed to only happen since iOS 9 so perhaps it warrants a search through your project for any categories like this.  I solved it by checking that the `UITextField`'s superview is the correct one:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[TTSInvestmentForecastValuesView class]])
        return NO;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```